# How to remove the second line of consecutive lines starting with the same word?

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have a text file with interchanging lines starting with 'TITLE' and 'DATA' but sometimes there are duplicate lines starting with 'TITLE':

> TITLE something
>   DATA some data
>   TITLE something else
>   DATA some other data
>   TITLE some more
>   TITLE extra info
>   DATA some more data

I'd like to be able to detect the duplicate lines starting with 'TITLE' and keep only the first line of each such pair.
I figured out that the regular expression for capturing these is `^TITLE.*\n^TITLE.*\n` now I'd like to incorporate this into a one-liner `perl`/`bash`/`sed`/`awk` command that would remove the second line and output the rest of the file, but I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: Bonus question : how to KEEP only the LAST such consecutive line ?

Comment: [Shortest solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15431290/1449460) : `uniq -w5 your_file`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'print unless $t and /^TITLE/; $t = /^TITLE/'
```

It remembers whether the previous line was a TITLE in the `$t` variable.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way you can do it with GNU sed:

```
sed -r 'N; /(TITLE)[^\n]*\n\1/ s/\n.*//; P; D' infile
```

- `N` puts a second line into pattern space.
- the match tests if both lines start with `TITLE`.
- if so the second line is removed.
- `P; D` prints and deletes the first line in pattern space.

Output:

```
TITLE something
DATA some data
TITLE something else
DATA some other data
TITLE some more
DATA some more data
```

#### Edit - handle arbitrary number of repetitions

As noted by *Nikina Reklawyks* in the comments the above solution only works with two consecutive lines starting with `TITLE`, to handle arbitrary number of repetitions, a simple loop can be added like this:

```
sed -r ':a; N; /(TITLE)[^\n]*\n\1/ s/\n.*//; ta; P; D' infile
```

The `ta` statement makes sed jump to the `:a` label when `s///` is  successful.

Another way of doing it, would be to use the `uniq` command from `coreutils`, this is not as flexible, but nevertheless works well in this case:

```
uniq -w5 infile
```

Comment: This only deletes the second of such consecutive lines, removing all but the first would be a natural desirable extension (imho). In other words, how to wrap this into a "run until the output doesn't change anymore" loop ? Anyhow, thanks for a useful starting point.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks: True, in this case it is easy to add a loop, see edit.

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
awk '$1!=p{print;p=$1}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you have records that consist of two fields, TITLE and DATA, and that if you're missing the second field, you want to drop the record.  But that's not what you asked in your question.  So here's one way to do what you asked:

```
awk '/^TITLE/&&!t{t=$0} /^DATA/&&t{print t;print;t=""}' inputfile
```

The idea here is that we'll set a variable to a TITLE when we see it and don't already have a titled set, then only print it when we see a DATA.  This works for the input data you provided, if I'm reading your question right.  Output is:

```
TITLE something
DATA some data
TITLE something else
DATA some other data
TITLE some more
DATA some more data
```

As you can see, the last TITLE line in your dataset was dropped.

And here's another way to do this in awk...

```
awk '/^TITLE/&&t{next} t=0; /^TITLE/{t=1} 1' inputfile
```

In this one, the first expression skips titles if `t` has ben set.  The second expression unsets `t`.  Third expression sets if for titles, and the last expression (`1`) prints the line.  Of course, the last three expressions don't get run if we skipped the line in the first expression.  It generates the same output as above, and doesn't bother looking at `/^DATA/`.

Finally, this one is the least code but the oddest logic:

```
awk '/^DATA/ || !t; {t=/^TITLE/}' inputfile
```

It prints all data lines, or any line where `t` isn't set, then effectively sets `t` to a boolean, affecting the next line's evaluation.  If you're doing this in csh or tcsh, beware of the exclamation point, which in those shells may need to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

try this one-liner:

```
 awk '/^TITLE/&&f{next;} {if ($0~/^TITLE/)f=1;else f=0}1' file
```

output:

```
TITLE something
DATA some data
TITLE something else
DATA some other data
TITLE some more
DATA some more data
```