# How to KEEP only the last line of consecutive lines starting with the same word?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

See this thread : [How to remove the second line of consecutive lines starting with the same word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430810/how-to-remove-the-second-line-of-consecutive-lines-starting-with-the-same-word)

Instead of keeping the first duplicate consecutive line starting with "TITLE", I would like to only keep the last one, to get from this input:

> TITLE something
>   DATA some data
>   TITLE something else
>   DATA some other data
>   TITLE some more
>   TITLE extra info
>   DATA some more data

This output:

> TITLE something
>   DATA some data
>   TITLE something else
>   DATA some other data
>   TITLE extra info
>   DATA some more data

Also, I'd like to be able to handle an arbitrary number of repetitions, and not only 2 (if by example 7 lines in a row start by "TITLE", only keep the last one).

Like the other post, it can be a `perl`/`bash`/`sed`/`awk` command that only keep the last line and output the rest of the file as well. I've been workng on this for a long time, but I could only find solutions that does the opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '/^TITLE/ { :a $! { N; /\nTITLE/ { s/.*\n//; ba; }; }; }' filename
```

That is:

```
/^TITLE/ {          # if a line begins with TITLE
  :a                # jump label for looping.
   $! {             # unless we hit the end of input (in case the file
                    # ends with title lines)
     N              # fetch the next line
     /\nTITLE/ {    # if it begins with TITLE as well
       s/.*\n//     # remove the first
       ba           # go back to a
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just reverse the order of lines, then print the now-first occurrence, then reverse them again:

```
$ tac file | awk '$1!=prev; {prev=$1}' | tac                  
TITLE something
DATA some data
TITLE something else
DATA some other data
TITLE extra info
DATA some more data
```

or if there can be multiple consecutive DATA lines and you want to keep all of those:

```
$ tac file | awk '!($1=="TITLE" && $1==prev); {prev=$1}' | tac
TITLE something
DATA some data
TITLE something else
DATA some other data
TITLE extra info
DATA some more data
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a Perl one-line solution, like the one in the question that you linked, then this will do

```
perl -ne'if (/^TITLE/) {$t = $_} else {print $t, $_; $t = ""}' myfile
```

Note that it will *not* print a `TITLE` line at all unless it is followed by a line that doesn't begin with `TITLE`

Comment: If the title can appear on the last line, you'll need to add `END { print $title }`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;/^(TITLE ).*\n\1/!P;D' file
```

This compares 2 lines and if the first is the same as the second does not print the first.